# Wrong value returned from function

Tags: contract-invocation, struct, mapping

I've a simple but problematic problem. I read a value of a struct from a smart contract with a function like this:

```
  function getOwner(address _id) constant returns (bytes32) {
    uint pos = ownerID[_id];
    Owner memory foundOwner;
    foundOwner = owners[pos];

    return foundOwner.name;
  }
```

Essentially I pass a key (in this case *_id*) that is used to get an index base on this mapping:

```
mapping(address => uint) public ownerID;
```

After I have the right index (*pos*), I copy the struct into a memory variable called *foundOwner*. At the end, I return the *name* field of the struct.

The problem is: If I have 2 ID registered, say ID1 and ID2:

- when I pass ID1 I get back ID1 name
- when I pass ID2 I get back ID2 name
- when I pass ID3 (with this sequence: ID1, ID2, ID3) I get back ID1 name, and this is a problem!

I know that with mapping, all the possible indexes are referenced so that the returned struct will have all fields set to 0x0.

I've also tried without the *memory variable*, returning directly `owners[pos].name`, but when I pass an unregistered ID, I always get back the element with the first index in the mapping.

*How can I be sure that when passing an ID not registered, the function returns an **empty struct**?*

Thanks in advice!

UPDATE: The Owner is set like this

```
  function registerOwner(bytes32 _name, bytes32 _surname) {
    owners.length++;
    uint pos = owners.length - 1;
    ownerID[msg.sender] = pos;
    owners[pos] = Owner(msg.sender, _name, _surname, true, block.number, block.timestamp);
  }
```

As I've said in the comments, my temporary solution is to create (within the constructor) a dummy variable with all *0x0* or *false* field. I think the problem is that when there is no match in the mapping, the *pos* variable will assume value 0, so returning the first entity I save. I think that maybe I can solve the problem simply starting from *pos=1*, so removing the -1 from line `uint pos = owners.length - 1;`

Comment: provide more information about the setter(setOwner) you use and the owners definition? you could provide the whole contract i could test it

Comment: For the moment I've solved creating a dummy entity (all fields at 0x0 or false) at pos=0. I think the problem is that when there is no matching, pos assumes the value 0, so returning the data for the first entity registered if it's registered with index 0. So now I have a dummy entity at pos=0 and the first real entity from pos=1. I don't think it's an elegant solution, but it's working.

Comment: @BadrBellaj I've updated the question with code about the registration of the owner.

Comment: Your solution is the one I see most often in practice. One question: Why not just map directly from address => Owner?  I don't really see the point of having the intermediate OwnerID step

Comment: @TjadenHess I decided to go with this mapping because I need to manage more owners (the word owner refers to something else, not to the contract) with an array `Owner[] public owners` . I've learned this approach a couple months ago when I started programming in Solidity: can I use without problem a direct `mapping address => Owner` also when there are a lot of Owners involved?

Comment: Yes, why would that be an issue?

Comment: @TjadenHess I've removed the array and with the direct mapping `address => Owner` everything is working correctly! Less line of code, less variables inside the contract and no dummy variable needed. When I pass an unregistered ID, it returns my a struct with all empty fields :)